# Why does not the gridview show any data while using linq2sql databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I tried this code inside the Page_Load block to bind the Northwind database and show the data to the gridview. There is no gridview while running it. Can you help me why this is happening? I found the solution nowhere, hope you know this.

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var products = from p in db.Products
               where p.ProductID == 2
               select p;

GridView1.DataSource = products;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute query and save results to list (or to array). Then assign this list to grid. Grid cannot be bound directly to query

```
GridView1.DataSource = products.ToList();
```